# Java DayOfWeek convert Day Name (String) to Day Number

Tags: java, java-time, dayofweek

I am trying to convert String value of a weekday to a Number.

I was looking into `Enum DayOfWeek` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), but it does not work the way I expected.

**Code**

```
String n = "MONDAY";

System.out.println(n); //prints MONDAY
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.valueOf(n)); //also prints MONDAY - should print 1
```

How can I get the corresponding number from my string instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `DayOfWeek`

Here you need to get the day-of-week int value. For that you need to use [`DayOfWeek.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) and [`DayOfWeek::getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getValue()). This works if your string inputs use the full English name of the day of week, as used on the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) enum objects.

```
 System.out.println(DayOfWeek.valueOf(n).getValue());
```

It returns the day-of-week, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).

Answer (score 4):

Look [at the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). Use [`getValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getValue--):

> Gets the day-of-week int value.
> The values are numbered following the
>   ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).

In your case

```
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.valueOf(n).getValue());
```

---

`DayOfWeek` is an enum that doesn't override `toString`, so the default behaviour is to print the name of the enum constant, which is ['MONDAY'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY). That's why you saw that behaviour.